# C# Remove certain amount of numbers end of line

Tags: c#

So,

I got example number: 0.00857382942837523 which length is 18, but I would like to remove from the end example 9 numbers. Thing is, that number is different every time, so I can't "predict" numbers what are going to be at the end.

//My question was marked to duplicate, but it can't be solved like that. Mine has 0.00, if I would do math.round it would give up 0...

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry I didn't find it. I will see if that's going to help me.

Comment: If you don't want to round, you may want to put your number in a string and cut that string? For a detailed answer you should tell us what the number of required decimals depend on and  what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Math.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        decimal d= 0.00857382942837523m;
        d= Math.Truncate(d * 1000000000m) / 1000000000m;
        Console.WriteLine(d); // 0.008573829
```